# msdeploy Parameters.xml deploy cannot set a value on node type 'Element'

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

For a load balanced web application I want to remove or add an element in web.config with setparameters.xml. Changing Attributes is working fine, but when I try to remove an entire element the following error appear in the verbose log from the generated cmd file during deploy: cannot set a value on node type 'Element'.

My config is as following (I want to remove the endpoint: name="A")

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint name="A" address="soap.udp://ip.adress" />
  <endpoint name="B" address="soap.udp://ip.adress" />
</client>
```

And a Parameters.xml with the following:

```
<parameter name="cacheFlushEndepunkt" description="cacheFlush" defaultValue="" tags="">
    <parameterValidation kind="AllowEmpty"/> 
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="Web\.config$" match="/configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint[@name='A']"/>
</parameter>
```

Is it possible to remove or add elements in web.config with ms deploy and setparameters?

Answer (score 0):

Your XPATH in match attribute of parameterEntry element seems to be not correct. Use following

```
//system.serviceModel/client/endpoint[@name='A']
```

or the same

```
//configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint[@name='A']
```

And section in parameters.xml to remove XML element from web.config looks like:

```
<parameter name="removeDnoaReporting" description="DotNetOpenAuth section" defaultValue="" >
        <parameterValidation kind="AllowEmpty" />
        <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="Web\.config$" match="//dotNetOpenAuth/reporting" />
    </parameter>
```

Comment: I agree that the // is necessary, however this does not solve the issue of remove or add entire elements with webdeploy.

Comment: You are right. Actually by me in parameters.xml is almost the as you have. But by me it works fine. Posted in answer. The main difference I see is tag attribute and \\. That's why I think that main problem could be with RegEx expression and \\